# Get access to another View from a Button's onClick method

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView in my app.
Its items have a Button and an invisible text field; I want to make the text field visible when the Button is pressed.
How can I do it from the `onClick(View v)` method of OnClickListener's object?

Maybe it's something like "getParent().findViewById()", but `getParent()` doesn't return a View..

Comment: post ur adapter code

Comment: Cant post my code due to notebook's battery is empty

Comment: `... notebook's battery is empty` ... Connect it to a power plug?!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the tag of the button view to the TextView.

Then you can use `v.getTag()` to get it back, then do what you want with it.

Otherwise, make the TextView final in your adapter getView method after finding it , then simply use it within the click event

Comment: OnClick method is in custom class. GetView method consists a line "view.findviewbyid(R.id.b1).setOnClickListener(cl1)" where cl1 is object of custom class that implements OnClickListener interface

Comment: I'm confused why you need a custom class for a click listener, but just pass the TextView as a constructor parameter to that class, then

Comment: You can create a class that holds both the current tag and the TextView. Then use that as the new tag

Comment: My listview has lot of items. I want to optimise code and use one Listener for each button. Thats why I created a myOnClickListener class outside an adapter; and only one object of this class

Comment: You can still use the one listener without an external class. You're micro optimizing in the wrong places

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visible the textView

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn:
                        yourtextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;

                        }
                        }
```

Comment: How can I get "yourtextview"?

Comment: TextView yourtextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

Comment: That won't work. `view` is the button, so you can not find from it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
View view = listview.getAdapter().getView(0,null,null);
TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```